# Git: merge behind changes

Tags: git, github, merge

Scenario:

- Computer A and Computer B have each cloned a git repository from Github.
- On Computer A, I make changes to a repository, commit, and push to Github.
- On Computer B, I make changes to other, unrelated files, and commit.
- On Computer B, I try to push, but cannot because I forgot to pull my changes first.
- On Computer B, I pull changes, and git creates a "Merge branch 'master' of github.com:user/repo" commit.
- On Computer B, I push changes to Github, but have an annoying and unnecessary "Merge" commit in the commit history.

How can I use `git merge` to place the merge commit *before* all my commits that have not been pushed? It's okay if this messes up the SHAs of the unpushed commits.

Do I need to `git rebase` something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way to avoid "annoying" merge commit:

```
git pull --rebase
```

This would automatically rebase your changes on computer B such that history appears to be linear. For more information about rebase, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666418/1734130).

If you have already pushed your merge commit from computer B to github, then it is too late: this merge commit will stay there forever. If not, you can still rebase. But it is easier to simply `git pull --rebase` to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `git pull` has a rebase behaviour by default, you can also put this in your configuration:

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

This option in the configuration will set the rebase behaviour when you pull for every branch. If you want to do a pull with a merge after setting this you can do it with the option `--no-rebase`.

```
git pull --no-rebase
```