# Is there a way to make git branch commit cleaner?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I have a git commit questions. We are three developers usually working on sprint environment. Attached is a screenshot of our commits look like.

Usually we will create a feature/Jira-1212_ticket_name and work on it. Then commit and do a PR that one of the others will review , then either approve or work more.

Finally all these feature branches get merged to develop branch as you can see.

However, it gets really like a snake. Is there a way to make it cleaner?

[image]

Comment: Uhm. I find this pretty clean. It's easy to follow branch and merge points and if your commit messages are good, I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git rebase` which is illustrated here: [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase)

If you always rebase (e.g. by `git pull --rebase`) you can get a linear history.  Some people prefer this, others think it's worse.  Up to you.

Comment: Usually I will create a feature branch and do git pull --rebase on that feature branch. Since we do the git pull on bitbucket, we use the bitbucket approve/merge functionality. That does merge of the branch to the develop branch. Are you suggesting merging locally and then push?

Comment: Yes I think that's right, you can rebase locally and then push.