# Rebased Git, but Changes Not Pulled?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-pull

I worked on a few commits while the `origin/master` moved forward, and then squashed them together on my local. I still have not committed anything, but even after running `git pull --rebase` there are still `origin/master` changes that are not in my local directory.

How could this be? `git status` shows clean.

Comment: How have you ascertained that there are still changes in `origin/master` ?

Comment: I am looking at a file that was changed, that I also changed, that has changes I do not. And `git status` shows clean. In fact, the lack of those changes in my local dir is causing a server error.

Comment: There is nothing necessarily wrong with this.  These other changes may have simply come in with the rebase.  If `git status` does not say that your branch is ahead/behind `origin/master`, then it isn't.

Comment: Sorry, it's ahead. By clean I meant no merge required or anything.

Comment: This looks completely normal, as you _should_ be ahead of `origin/master` after a rebase.  Nothing is wrong here.

Comment: I am ahead, but I am missing changes? That is normal?

Comment: Where does it say you are missing changes?  If you _are_ missing changes, then the rebase didn't work.  It is _possible_ that you are missing changes from the remote `master` branch.  But even in this case, you would not know this from what `git status` shows you, because it uses `origin/master` to report this.

Comment: Shouldn't it have merged those changes in with my changes and caused a conflict or just merged them in with my changes when I rebased? Now if I push, the `origin/master` would lose those changes.

Comment: `origin/master` is a _local_ branch on your computer.  It is _not_ what is in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I run `git pull --rebase` then it is what is in the remote repository though? That is what I have done. So what I meant is that the remote `origin/master` repository would lose those changes.

Comment: `origin/master` is what actually gets updated when you do a `git fetch`.  So, if you did a `git fetch` _immediately_ before your rebase, then yes, you rebased on the remote `master` branch.  But not necessarily.  Even if new stuff has come into the remote, you would find this out when you tried to push.

Comment: Isn't `git pull --rebase` exactly just that? A `fetch` and a `rebase`? Why would it tell me when I go to `push`? Because the history is different? But the history is the same. I have the same commits.

Comment: Good point, the fetch and rebase might be atomic, but that wouldn't matter if someone else pushed to `master` before you had a chance to fast-forward it.

Comment: My advice: Come back here when you have a real question.  This isn't a good way to learn Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout to the project that you want to rebase with origin/master.

> git checkout

Do a rebase from your current branch to the master branch

> git rebase master

If your branch is forked from branch "previous" and you want to fork it from master then

> git rebase previous master

Further read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase/16666418#16666418)