# How to remove commits from other's in merge request

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I now encounter a problem when I pull a remote branch.

Once I resolved all in case of the conflict, I have to commit all their changes.

So that once I create merge request, it includes all of them.
Thus it's hard to review. I just want to have only my commit at the moment.

How would you resolve those conflict in order to make a merge request easier to be reviewed?

I got more question as below:

Let's say I got 2 branches: `A has commits (a, b)` `B has commits (c, d)`. I also have created the merge requests (MR) (`MR-A`, `MR-B`) to `master`. So that `MR-A has (a, b)` and `MR-B has (c, d)` commits inside. But if I am at the `A` branch then I rebase the branch `B` so that `MR-A has (a, b, c, d)` commits while `MR-B also has (c, d)`. Finally I merge `MR-A` to `master`. However the `MR-B still has (c, d)`

And the question is: How could I remove the `c, d` from `MR-B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `pull` only (not `pull --rebase`) then the resolution of a merge involves a commit (and not `git add` + `git rebase --continue`)

That means you can make one or *several* commits to full resolve the conflict detected after a git pull.

So all you need to do is a `git add -p`, to add only hunks of the conflicted files:

- first the hunks of code that are not yours
- then yours

That way, you end up with *separate* commits. And you can make a more precise merge request, easier to review.

This is harder to do with a rebase, which will make only one commit once you have fixed and added to the index the files with conflicts.

---

> How could I remove the c, d from MR-B?

You don't: you simply delete MRB: if you have rebased MRA on top of MRB, and then merge MRA to master, MRB does not have any role: all its commits have been merged.

If MRB has more commits, and you want to remove b and c, simply do a `git rebase -i`: that will rebase MRB in interactive mode, allowing you to drop commits b and c, keeping other commits. Force push MRB and you can continue working on fix B.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @VonC. Could you take a look above to see what I edited and help me to answer that question?

Comment: I got it. Thanks your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Rebase is what you are looking for, not merge.

Read:
[When do you use git rebase instead of git merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)
[What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase)