# Git difference between pull and rebase from a parent stream

Tags: git

I have created a branch out of develop branch. Now to get develop branch changes into my feature branch should I use **git rebase origin/develop** or **git pull** and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase)

Comment: The question should be _Should I use git rebase or git merge?_ The answers is simple. It's all up to you. Merge will make one addition commit after applying changes from develop brunch. With rebase changes will migrate without any extra commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your branch has not been pushed before, you can rebase it on top of the updated develop branch (`origin/develop`)

```
git fetch
git checkout yourBranch
git rebase origin/develop
```

See more in [my 2009 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)

The fact that you have branched locally from the local branch `develop` does not prevent you to rebase on top of an *updated* `develop` branch: that is the one from the *remote* repo: `origin/develop`.
You would rebase on top of `develop` only if you were the only one working on that repo, and if you added yourself local commits to that local `develop` branch.

Comment: Thanks - please confirm what git pull will do? Note that I have branched from develop and not origin/develop.

Comment: @Prakash pull would fetch then merge origin/master, from your GitHub repo, which includes the file(s) added at the repo creation: those files would be merged/assed to your local repo, allowing you then to push back only your changes.

Comment: @Prakash you usually rebase on top of origin/develop, unless you added yourself commits to the local develop branch.