# Does the direction or order of a merge/rebase make a difference?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, rebase

Let's say you pull from a remote repository while you're working on your feature branch and new commits are added to the master branch.

You finish working on the feature branch, commit your changes and then merge/rebase it onto master. Where in the master branch are the feature commits inserted, before or after the pulled commits? Where are they inserted if you never performed a pull?  Will it have the same result?

Also, what happens if you merge/rebase master onto the feature branch instead of the other way around? Where is master inserted into the feature branch if you merged/rebase before or after the pull?  Will it have the same result?  Will its history look any different from the aforementioned merge/rebase of the feature into the master?

More succinctly, do the direction of the merge and/or order of the merge have different outcomes on the resulting merge?  I suspect it doesn't matter.

**ASIDE**: This question may be easy to answer for someone who Gits it, but with the hundreds, if not thousands, of documentation and tutorial resources out there, I've never seen it addressed directly. Without knowing the answer, Git can be extremely confusing to understand.

Because the order of operations is important in some Git concepts and in programming in general, it can lead someone to conclude it makes a difference. Moreover, we normally tend to think of revisions as occuring in chronological sequence and expect Git to work the same way. The user interfaces and commandline also play into this perception by implying an order of operations.

Other version tracking tools do a far better job of abstracting this cognitively corrosive operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> Moreover, we normally tend to think of revisions as occurring in chronological sequence and expect Git to work the same way.

This is a terrible mistake.  Git works in *graph order*, not chronological order.  When the graph order is chronological—which is sometimes, but not always—*then* it works OK.

## Long

(I'm not even going to touch on rebase here.  For a proper discussion of rebase, see earlier postings.  I'm just going to concentrate on the symmetries in merging, and the places where the seams can show.)

> More succinctly, do the direction of the merge and or order of the merge have different outcomes on the resulting merge? I suspect it doesn't matter.

The answer is both no and yes.

To understand *why* this is the answer, you need to understand several things about Git.

First, let's consider how Git treats commits, in contrast to how many others do it (most others? all others? there must be at least one other VCS that does this too...).  In version control systems, the process of *making a commit in a branch* adds the new commit *to* the branch; but in Git, the set of branches that hold a commit *once it is made* can be, and is, something that changes dynamically.  That is, the commit, once made, is *independent of any branch*, and can, if you wish, be made on *no* branch.

In Mercurial, for instance, this is quite impossible.  While Mercurial is otherwise very much like Git in many ways, the existence of a commit *requires* the existence of its branch.  The commit is made *on* that branch, and forevermore is *part of* that branch.  That is the *only* branch that holds the commit: the commit is permanently affixed to its branch.

In both Git and Mercurial, each commit has a unique ID, and each commit stores the unique ID of its *parent* (singular) commit, if it is an ordinary commit.  By following this backwards-looking chain, starting from the *last* commit and working backwards, we can find the history of commits on the branch:

```
...  <-grandparent  <-parent  <-child
```

In Mercurial, these commits are forever on their branch, so we can write the branch name on the left:

```
branch-A:  ...--I--J
```

Finding the latest commit in Mercurial is easy as commits have a simple sequential number in the local repository (along with a unique hash ID that is used for sharing between repositories).

In Git, though, the branch *names* are moveable.  Before commit `J` exists, the name `branch-A` stores the raw hash ID of commit `I`:

```
...--H--I   <-- branch-A
```

When making a new commit, Git simply writes the new commit's hash ID into the branch name, so that the branch points to the new commit:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- branch-A
```

## Merge is both a noun and a verb

In version control, *merging*, the verb, or *to merge* some commits, is a process.  The result—at least in both Git and Mercurial—is a *merge commit*, where we use the word *merge* as an adjective modifying *commit*, or for short, *a merge* (a noun).

What makes merge commits *be* merge commits is that they have *two* parents, bringing two lines of development together:

```
...--I--J
         \
          M
         /
...--K--L
```

Here, again, Git and Mercurial are basically the same, with one really important difference:  In Mercurial, the merge commit is specifically on *one* branch, that being whichever branch you are on when you run `hg merge`.  Commits—including merge commits—are permanently affixed to their branches.  Once the process of merging is complete and the merge commit exists, that merge commit is on that one branch.  In Git, the merge commit goes onto the current branch, but because we can move the *name*, in some sense it does not matter.

But we have to look at both parts: the verb part, *to merge*, and then closely at the noun part, *a merge*.  (Aside: Git also allows merge commits to have *more than two* parents, while Mercurial restricts each merge to two parents.  There's nothing that these funky merges, which Git calls *octopus merges*, can do that you cannot do with a series of pairwise merges, but an octopus merge can show intent more clearly in some cases.)

#### To merge, the verb

Suppose, for instance, that `branch-A` and `branch-B` were like this before the merge:

```
...--I--J   <-- branch-A

...--K--L   <-- branch-B
```

Before we can merge these, we have to trace *both* histories back far enough to find the *merge base*, the common commit from which these two lines of development diverged.  (This is true in Mercurial too.)  So let's fill in a bit more:

```
       I--J   <-- branch-A
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- branch-B
```

Here, commit `H` is the common starting point.  In Git, commit `H` is on *both branches at the same time* (but not in Mercurial).  Still, both version control systems do the *to merge* process in pretty much the same way: you start by picking one commit to check out, such as commit `J` using `git checkout branch-A` or `hg update branch-A`.  Then you pick the other commit using the command's `merge` verb: `git merge branch-B` or `hg merge branch-B`.  The VCS finds the appropriate merge base, i.e., commit `H`, and compares the contents of `H` to the contents of `J` to see what *you* changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

and repeats this same comparison to find what *they* changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git combines these changes into one big "all changes", applies those changes to the *base* (commit `H`), and makes the new commit.

(Mercurial does much the same, though there are some very important differences in terms of how Mercurial knows about renames.  These only matter if you have renamed some files since the merge base.  If you *have* renamed files, and have a rename/rename conflict, the merge order becomes very important.  But let's assume there are no rename issues.)

The main interesting thing here is that you have control over *how* the changes are combined.  In Git, you do this through the *merge strategy* and *extended strategy arguments*; in Mercurial, you do this through the chosen *merge tool*.  If you use an "ours" strategy/tool, the VCS completely ignores their changes: the combined changes are just *your* changes, so the VCS makes the new merge commit using the *same code* as in the current commit.  Here the merge order obviously matters: if we're ignoring *their* changes, we had best be sure who is "us"!

Even without an "ours" strategy, there may be conflicts between your changes and their changes.  If so, both Git and Mercurial can be told: *prefer mine* or *prefer theirs*.  These will give different results, so here again, the merge order matters.  Of course, at this point there's a symmetric option: *choose mine* or *choose theirs*.  If you swap roles, you can swap options—so while order matters, it's less crucial.

#### A merge, the noun

Let's assume there are no conflicts and no special ours/theirs happenings, and run `git checkout branch-A; git merge branch-B`.  If all goes well, the VCS makes the merge commit `M` with its two parents:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- branch-A
      \    /
       K--L   <-- branch-B
```

In Mercurial, the merge order matters here, because once commit `M` is made, it's stuck to its branch forever.  But Git lets us *move the branch names* after the fact.  We can make `M` like this, leave it where it is, shove `branch-A` back one step to point to `J` again, and then move `branch-B` forward to point to `M`, giving:

```
       I--J   <-- branch-A
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- branch-B
      \    /
       K--L
```

which is pretty much the same as what we would get if we did `git checkout branch-B; git merge branch-A`.  So it seems like here, the merge order is irrelevant (provided there were no hitches during the *verb* part).  But there's something missing from the diagram here, and that's the notion of *first* and *not-first* parents!

The *first* parent of merge commit `M`, in both Git and Mercurial, is the "same branch" parent.  That is, since we were on commit `J` when we ran the merge, the *first* parent of `M` is commit `J`.  That leaves `L` as the *second* parent.  If we shove the branch labels around in Git, we can tell that we have done so, because the first and second parents will still be in the other order.

So we see here that for Git, even when the *to merge* verb has no ordering issues, the resulting *merge commit* (adjective or noun) does have an order to it.  It's up to you, the user, to decide whether that order matters to you.  If not, the symmetry is available.  If the commit parent order matters, the direction/order of the merge is as critical in Git as it is in Mercurial.

## The graph is the key

In any graph-based version control system—hence in both Git and Mercurial—the graph *is* the history.  In Git in particular, there is no such thing as *file history;* the graph is not only the *primary* history, it's the *only* history.  (Mercurial stores file data in a more conventional fashion, so there is both commit history *and* file history, but the file history is not useful without the commit history anyway.)

To be able to understand what Git does and why, you need to know enough graph theory to drive or ride public transit around a city.  That's not all that much much—but if you don't realize that Git has these one-way railroad tracks / streets / bridges, leading from the *last* commits back towards the *first*, many things will make no sense.  Git starts at the end, and works backwards to the beginning.  The branch names get you into the graph, at the branch-tip ends.  Everything else is a function of the commit graph.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the amazing amount of effort and thought you put forward in helping me understand Git.  I just realized there's an entire cottage industry focused solely on understanding Git. It seems like every month or so, some brave soul attempts to distill Torvald’s Aspergers mind into something normal people can grasp. 

I also realized that I’ve lost many man months of productivity working with it. If it wasn’t free and or didn’t have the star power of Linus Torvalds, it wouldn't be used at all.

Comment: It might not be. Mercurial, in particular, is *way* more beginner-friendly, in part due to having better default settings than Git. But I've used a number of pre-Git/Hg VCSes and, as bad as Git is with some things, it's a huge step forward over various predecessors (both free and commercial).

Answer (score 2):

> You finish working on the feature branch, commit your changes and then merge/rebase it onto master.
>
> Where in the master branch are the feature commits inserted, before or after the pulled commits?

After: the merge/rebase will consider the current state of the master branch.
If that branch has evolved (with a pull), then the merge/rebase will use the current master HEAD (which now references the pulled commits)

> Where are they inserted if you never performed a pull?

Same: it will use the current master HEAD (which don't reflect any new commits, since no pull has been done)

> Will it have the same result?

No, considering master HEAD is different in both cases.

> Also, what happens if you merge/rebase master onto the feature branch instead of the other way around?

First, don't: that is not a best practice.
But if you do, that merge/rebase will use the feature HEAD.

> Where is master inserted into the feature branch if you merged/rebase before or after the pull? Will it have the same result?

Same result, since in both case, it uses the feature HEAD, which hasn't changed when you do (or do not do) a pull on master.

Comment: Damn!  I'm confused again.  So order makes a difference?  The entire master is replayed onto the tiny feature branch?  This is unclear.

Comment: @ATL_DEV What part is unclear? A->B is not the same as B->A. Source and destination matter.

Comment: Well, source and destination implies a certain order. What does the history look like after rebasing and or merging the master onto the feature branch?  My guess is the master branch is emptied and its commits are replayed on top of the feature branch.  This would mean the feature branch's commit appear first in history?  If so, Git sucks!!,

Comment: @ATL_DEV As I said in the answer: don't rebase master, that is not a good practice. Merging won't empty master though. See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing. Also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

When you merge, both remote and your local commits are fully preserved intact, and merge commit refers to both of them.

When you rebase, remote commits are preserved (or at least they should be preserved!), and your local commits are applied on top of it. Never try to force git to rebase in other direction, it's recipe for disaster.

For more information about merge vs rebase difference, read this answer [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase/16666418#16666418)

Comment: I understand, the difference between merge and rebase.  So git rebase is ordered, while merge is just a unordered sequence  of commits?

Comment: Merge commit refers to both remote and local commit histories (they are unaltered), in that sense there is no real order. Rebase commit is exactly the same as merge (content-wise), but it loses link to your local commit history. Again, look at the picture in a link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

> TLDR: `Merge`, merges argument branches into checkout branch,
> `rebase`, rebase puts checkout branch on top of argument branch (ie, ahead of, in the future, nearest to now)

## Merge affects checkout branch label advancement, order not a concern

For instance, the branch(s) supplied to `git merge A B` will be merged into the checkout branch

**(not a big deal, if you make a mistake)** *hint*: `git branch -f <oops-branch> <go-back-to-commit>  # don't be on oops-branch`

**Do it this way**

99% of the time what you want to do is to checkout some branch `git checkout A` then merge the other branch into it `git merge B`

✅ `$ git merge B  #I am on branch A, megre B into A`

[image]

Branch **A** label is advanced to merge commit, while **B** is not.

## Rebase order affects which commits get rewritten

**(kind of a big deal, but you can recover from a mistake)** *hint*: `git branch -f <oops-branch> <go-back-to-commit>  # don't be on oops-branch`

**Do it this way**

99% of the time you just want to use rebase to pull changes from a branch into your dev branch. This `rebase` syntax is in opposition to the idiomatic way of merging shown above (ie, to checkout branch `A' then `merge` branch 'B' into 'A')

`rebase`  imagine roasting marshmallows on a stick, the last marshmallow stacks on top of the previous. That's how `rebase` syntax works.

✅ `$ git rebase main dev  #I am on branch main but it doesn't matter what branch I am on bc I've explicitly told git the rebase order, rebase dev on top of main`

[image]

[image]

**DO NOT do it this way**

Can you see the problem here?

❌ `$ git rebase dev  #I am on branch main, rebases main on top of dev`

[image]

[image]