# get changes from master after creating branch

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I am using `Egit` with `eclipse` for working on my java project. I created a branch called `branch1` from master and started working on it.

In the mean time my colleague created another branch `branch2` from master, made some changes and merged `branch2` back to master.

Now I need to get all the changes that were made on master to my branch `branch1`.

How can I achieve this using `eclipse` or `github` and **not using any command**.

Comment: You could either [rebase your branch to the latest master commit](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Rebasing), merge the changes from master into your branch or cherry pick all commits from master that you want.

Comment: now I am confused about what to choose between merge and rabase which is new to me.

Comment: Rebasing and merging leads to different histories. It's your choice what you want. If there are none or only few conflicts, I would prefer rebasing: make sure `branch1` is checked-out and in the _History_ view right-click the latest `master` commit (make sure _Show All Branches and Tags_ is enabled, otherwise only `branch1` commits are visible) and choose _Rebase on_.

Comment: @howlger thanks for your answer. Since I am quite new with git, could you please elaborate steps on answer section.

Comment: Which of the two steps are you stuck on? 1. Make sure `branch1` is checked-out (the project name should be decorated with `[branch1]`; 2. In the _History_ view right-click the latest master commit and choose _Rebase on_.

Comment: I checked out `branch1`. Now Do i have to do team->rebase on eclipse? i don't see anything on History view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183313/discussion-between-user9735824-and-howlger).

Comment: To see also commits of `master` in the _History_ view you have to enable _Show All Branches and Tags_ (the button in the right upper corner of the _History_ view).

Comment: i don't see the button you are talking.

Comment: Here, the button to the right of the _Compare Mode_ button: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13dka9ut-xs&t=120s

Answer (score 6):

**Using Eclipse/EGit:**

1. Open the "Git Repositories" View
2. Make sure `branch1` is checked out (respectively the branch you want to update with changes of the remote `master` branch).
3. Right-click the repository you're working on and click on `Fetch from Upstream`. This will fetch information about new commits on the remote repository (in your case the new commits that were added to the master branch after your branch (`branch1`) was created).
   [image]
4. Expand the `Remote Tracking` node and right-click the `master` branch. Select either `Merge` or `Rebase on`. Both options update your branch (`branch1`) with the changes that meanwhile were added to the `master` branch.[image]

The difference between `Merge` and `Rebase on`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666418/5207900