# How to update a branch based on another one?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two branches X and Y. I've changed something in Y and I want to update X based on the changes in Y. I have changes in X as well, but I don't want to update branch Y.

How do I update one branch based on another without deleting one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways: merging or rebasing.

For merging:

```
git checkout X
git merge Y
```

For rebasing:

```
git checkout X
git rebase Y
```

Some links below:

- [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase)
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 0):

Just `git checkout X && git merge Y`

And solve conflicts if there are any