# How to update git brach, created from another branch?

Tags: git

**Scenario**: Have 2 git branches main and develop. From develop branch I created a new branch with the name test. Did some changes in the test branch and am ready to merge it into the main branch. But before merging I need to get other changes made by another user to develop the branch and keep mine. Only after it, I can merge the test to the main.

Precondition: 2 branches main and develop

Step 1: create new branch develop -> test

Step 2: add some code to test branch

Step 3: bring changes from develop -> test (Note: update and keep my changes in test)

Step 4: merge test -> main

How can I perform step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple approaches here would be to either merge `develop` into `test` or rebase `test` on `develop`.  The merge option:

```
# from test
git fetch origin
git merge origin/develop
```

The rebase option:

```
# from test, again
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/develop
```

Assuming that you have already done a fetch recently and you have the latest changes in `develop`, you may merge/rebase directly on local `develop` and drop the `git fetch` steps above.

Answer (score 0):

There two approaches to do that, depending on how you want to build history tree. To distinguish git merge vs git rebase, I highly recommend you should read [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase) and [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing)