# Which is recommended git rebase or git merge to include the changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, bitbucket-cloud

I am working on `branch A` which was created from `branch B` which was created from `master`.
Now master has moved ahead and I want to include the master branch changes into A.
`How can I do that?`

I have done this in the past by merging master into branch A. But I am not sure if that is a good approach.
I have heard a lot about `doing a rebase` from the master but not sure what's the difference as ultimately I just want the new code to be there in the branch A

Comment: "ultimately I just want the new code to be there in the branch A" Reverse merging accomplishes that, so what's the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm pretty sure there are tons of similar questions - and answers - covering this topic, but nevertheless.

Your history is `master -> B -> A`.

And it looks like you want to go to `new-master -> new-A` (no `B` anymore).

Or in other words, you want to get to a situation where your work branch `A` contains your changes on top of whatever is currently in master.

### Rebase

In this case, you pretty much always want to *rebase* your local changes on top of that new master.

What *rebase* does is that it takes each commit that you made on top of the "old master" and "re-applies" them on top of the "new master".

Assuming there are no conflicts - as those could possible make a rebase a bit more challenging at first sight (but there is a remedy to it) - and let's say you made 5 commits to your work branch.

After the *rebase*, your new work branch will still contain 5 commits - but with **different** commit SHA's as those will be **rewritten** - on top of the latest "master".

### Merge

Same setup, no conflicts and you made 5 commits in your branch.

After the *merge*, all of these commits will still exist with their existing SHA's - and there will be a 6th commit, a so-called "merge commit" that will take all of master's changes and merge them onto your branch.

### When to choose which

Since *rebase* will re-apply your local changes on top of the new master, their commit SHA's will change.

However, you will end up in a situation where it will be much easier for you to eventually upstream your changes because your history will look like `new-master -> your 5 commits -> HEAD`.

Whereas a *merge* will not touch those old commits - but yield a history such as `master -> your 5 commits -> all changes between old and new master in a single merge commit -> HEAD`.

This can often be much harder to eventually merge upstream.

### Rebasing a large number of commits

In case your work branch has a larger number of local changes, but you still want to rebase, one thing you could do to help with potential merge conflicts is to first *squash* your changes prior to the rebase.

Comment: "Well, I'm pretty sure there are tons of similar questions - and answers - covering this topic" Then do not answer. Vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @matt I marked my answer as community wiki because I kinda agree with you - just didn't want to be overly harsh to a new contributor.

Comment: @MartinBaulig Thanks a lot. Could you briefly describe what you mean by `eventually upstream your changes` and how will rebase help in it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use git merge (not because it's "more correct", but because it keeps complete track of all commits). Use git rebase when you are looking for that specific behaviour ( [What's the difference between 'git merge' and 'git rebase'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase) ), but if case of doubt, git merge for sure will not mess with your repo. Of course, pay attention to correctly manage any conflict that git cannot automatically address.