# Merge commit into branch other than master

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull-request

I have the origin branch as master, now I have to make one branch named old-master and make changes and merge commit to it which means for the changes I have to make old-master as origin and do the changes using another new branch i.e the changes should be pushed using new branch and should be merged into old-master

I was using rebase using git but more precise answer would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What has "origin" got to do with merging? What is the problem? `git checkout old-master; git merge branch` merges branch into old-master. Branches are nothing more than names and you can merge any branch into any other branch.

Comment: Yeah... it starts to read like Pinoccio and a couple of lines later it is The Lord of the Rings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase

Does this answer your question?